# Best way to send a goal with move_base that is off the global costmap?

Tags: mapping, ros-hydro, costmap, navfn, global-costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Guys,

Using Hydro's navigation stack and move_base, I am trying to send a goal/waypoint to the robot that is at least 1000 meters away from the robots current position, if not more.

The local planner that I am using is: dwa_local_planner/DWAPlannerROS

The global planner that I am using is: navfn/NavfnROS

For the local and global costmap, I do not have a "static_map", so that is false, and I have turned rolling_window to true.

What is the best way to send a waypoint that is pretty far away from the robots current position without growing the size of the global costmap to be 1000 x 1000 meters or larger?

I do not want to have the robot plan the whole distance at once, as this would take a very long time, but plan as it goes, maybe every 20 meters without stopping, to get to the 1000 meter waypoint.

Is there a way to do this with the navigation stack?

Thank you in advance for your responses.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/142986/best-way-to-send-a-goal-with-move_base-that-is-off-the-global-costmap?/) by [Raptor](https://answers.ros.org/users/3237/raptor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 377 on 2014-03-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There currently is no way to do this in the navigation stack without making the very large costmap. If you can describe how you think it should work, please open a ticket. https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/issues?state=open

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2014-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suggest you use this:
http://wiki.ros.org/yocs_waypoints_navi

It allows you to set waypoints throw where the robot will go before reaching the final goal.
Tell me if you have any problem using it.

---

Originally posted by [AbuIbra](https://answers.ros.org/users/6791/abuibra/) with karma: 118 on 2014-03-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1